# CRUD Laravel 5 how to link to destroy of Resource Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a link

```
<a class="trashButton" href="{{ URL::route('user.destroy',$members['id'][$i]) }}" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

this link is supposed to direct to the destroy method of the Usercontroller , this is my route `Route::resource('/user', 'BackEnd\UsersController');`

UserController is a  Resource Controller. But at this moment it is directing me to the show method rather than directing to the destroy method

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because you are requesting the resources via GET method instead DELETE method. Look:

```
DELETE  /photo/{photo}  destroy     photo.destroy
GET     /photo/{photo}  show    photo.show
```

Both routes have the same URL, but the header verb identifies which to call. Looks the [RESTful table](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). For example, via ajax you can send a DELETE request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/user/4',
    type: 'DELETE',  // user.destroy
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Comment: is there a way I could send the method via URL::route so that laravel can understand its a delete method,  instead using ajax or maybe anything else @manix

Comment: Via web browser, I don't think so. You could consider make a controller instead of a Resource. With a basic controller you can declare a function that can delete the user.

Comment: @manix When I am doing same, it's firing TokenMismatchException exception. even though I am sending csrf token with the ajax request. Please guide

Answer (score 43):

You need to send a `DELETE` request instead of a `GET` request. You can't do that with a link, so you have to use an AJAX request or a form.

Here is the generic form method:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('user.destroy', $members['id'][$i]) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button>Delete User</button>
</form>
```

If you're using **Laravel 5.1 or later** then you can use Laravel's built-in helpers to shorten your code:

```
<form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $members['id'][$i]) }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button>Delete User</button>
</form>
```

If you're using **Laravel 5.6 or later** then you can use the new Blade directives to shorten your code even further:

```
<form action="{{ route('user.destroy', $members['id'][$i]) }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button>Delete User</button>
</form>
```

You can read more about [method spoofing in Laravel here.](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: Note that the input fields can be shortened to `{{ method_field("DELETE") }}` and `{{ csrf_field() }}` respectively.

Comment: @AI0867 True, if you're using version 5.1 or later.

Comment: Please note with Laravel `5.6` you have again shorter code: `@csrf` and `@method('DELETE')` (not tested on my side, sorry).

Comment: how can i do this with ajax?

Comment: @LuísAlmeida You would set the method on your AJAX call to `DELETE` as described in the accepted answer by @manix, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30299435/4245525

Answer (score 16):

I use this template 'resources/views/utils/delete.blade.php'

```
<form action="{{ $url or Request::url() }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type='submit' class="{{ $class or 'btn btn-danger' }}" value="{{ $value or 'delete' }}">{!! $text or 'delete' !!}</button>
</form>
```

Called as this:

```
@include('utils.delete',array( 'url' => URL::route('user.destroy',$id),'text' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> delete me'))
```

Comment: `{{ csrf_field() }}` and `{{ method_field('FOO') }}` are out-dated when you have Laravel 5.6, see my comment some answers above.

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking to do this via a regular link instead of through AJAX or another type of form request you can set up a special route that will respond to a normal `GET` request:

In your routes, define this in addition to the resource:

```
Route::get('user/{site}/delete', ['as' => 'user.delete', 'uses' => 'UserController@destroy']);
```

In your view:

```
<a href="{{ route('user.delete', $user->id) }}">Delete this user</a>
```

In your controller:

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{
  $user->delete();
  return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

Comment: While this works, it assigns a destructive action to a GET request, and is vulnerable to CSRF.

Comment: this is a dangerous behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

If we need to use an anchor to trigger the destroy route, and we don't want to use ajax, we can put a form inside our link, and submit the form using the `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).find('form').submit();" >
    <form action="{{ url('/resource/to/delete') }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    </form>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to visit the destroy action on delete route by HTML, then there is an approach to use HTTP Method Spoofing which means that you could visit a delete HTTP method by adding a hidden input named `_method` with the value of `"DELETE". Same way can be used for "PUT" and "PATCH" HTTP method.

Below is a sample for DELETE method.

```
<form action="/tasks/5" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

will get the route

```
DELETE  /tasks/{id}  destroy     tasks.destroy
```

if you use laravel collective, you can write this way in your views.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/tasks/'.$cat->id, 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone came here to find how to replace standard laravel form for delete, from button in it to link, you can just replace:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['tasks.destroy', $task->id],'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("Are you sure?")', 'id'=>'himan']) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Delete') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

TO

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['tasks.destroy', $task->id],'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("Are you sure?")', 'id'=>'himan']) !!}

    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();">Delete</a>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Just replace button with simple `<a href="#"...` but with `onclick` attribute to submit the form!

Answer (score 1):

**GET** and **DELETE** Both routes have the same URL, but the header verb identifies which to call.

Here are my code snippets for edit and delete. I use bootstrap modal confirmation for delete action

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="{{ route('locations.edit', $location->id) }}"
   class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </a>
  <span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm formConfirm"
      data-form="#frmDelete-{{$location->id}}"
      data-title="Delete Location"
      data-message="Are you sure you want to delete this Location ?">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </span>
<form method="POST"
      style="display: none"
      id="frmDelete-{{$location->id}}"
      action="{{ route('locations.destroy' , $location->id) }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**BootStrap Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formConfirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span
                        class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="frm_title">Delete</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="frm_body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button style='margin-left:10px;' type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-2 pull-right"
                    id="frm_submit">Yes
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-2 pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" id="frm_cancel">
                No
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And Finally JS code**

```
$('.formConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = $(this);
  var title = el.attr('data-title');
  var msg = el.attr('data-message');
  var dataForm = el.attr('data-form');

  $('#formConfirm')
    .find('#frm_body').html(msg)
    .end().find('#frm_title').html(title)
    .end().modal('show');

  $('#formConfirm').find('#frm_submit').attr('data-form', dataForm);
});

$('#formConfirm').on('click', '#frm_submit', function (e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-form');
  $(id).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My, non-ajax version. I use it in dropdowns (bootstrap) in resource list (datatables as well). Very short and universal.

Global jQuery method:

```
$('.submit-previous-form').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this)).prev('form').submit();
});
```

And then we can use everywhere something like this:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['user.destroy', $user], 'method' => 'delete']) }} {{ Form::close() }}
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item submit-previous-form" title="Delete user"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete him</a>
```

Recommend: It's easy to integrate with confirms scripts for example swal.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: (you can pass your id)

```
<form action="{{ route('tasks.destroy', $dummy->id) }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="this.closest('form').submit();return false;">
              <i class="bi bi-trash-fill" style="color:white"></i>
           </a>
 </form>
```

requires route like:

```
Route::get('/tasks/delete/{id}', 'TasksController@destroy')
     ->name('tasks.destroy');
```

your controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->delete();
    return redirect('/home')->with('success','Task Deleted Successfully');
}
```

or you can try this

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['reports.destroy', $dummy->id],'class'=>'']) !!}
      {{ Form::button('<i class="bi bi-trash-fill" style="color:white"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'delete get-started-btn-two'] )  }}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a link, you can use a library I have created that lets people make links that behave like POST, DELETE... calls.

https://github.com/Patroklo/improved-links