# How to solve MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:?

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $user->id !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $user->username !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $user->phone !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $user->address !!}</td>
        <td>
            {!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy.year', $user->id, $year], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
            <div class='btn-group'>
                <a href="{!! route('users.edit', [$user->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')"]) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

My routes\web.php is like this :

```
Route::get('users/destroy/{year}', 'UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy.year');

Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

My controller is like this :

```
public function destroy($id, $year)
{
    $user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($user)) {
        Flash::error('User not found');

        return redirect(route('users.index.year', ['year' => $year]));
    }

    $this->userRepository->delete($id);

    Flash::success('User deleted successfully.');

    return redirect(route('users.index.year', ['year' => $year]));
}
```

There is exist error like this :

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

And the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/2?2016`

When click button delete, I want the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016`

Is there any people who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you have declared the form method as `DELETE`; but in the `routes\web.php` file, you have declared the route as `GET`

Change the view

```
{!! Form::open(
    ['route' => ['users.destroy.year', $user->id, $year],
    'method' => 'get']
  )!!}
```

Your `routes/web.php` should look like so,

```
Route::get('users/index/{year}', 'UserController@index')
     ->name('users.index.year');
Route::get('users/destroy/{id}/{year}', 'UserController@destroy')
     ->name('users.destroy.year');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController', ['except' => ['index', 'destroy']]);
```

Keep your controller code as it is.

This should do the trick.

---

**Just a suggestion**

It's better not to keep *delete* operation on `GET` request. So change the `DELETE` route like so

```
Route::delete('users/destroy/{id}/{year}', 'UserController@destroy')
     ->name('users.destroy.year');
```

Change the view

```
{!! Form::open(
    ['route' => ['users.destroy.year', $user->id, $year],
    'method' => 'delete']
  )!!}
```

Comment: I using http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/ or https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/adminlte-generator/tree/5.3. Seems the delete have been generated automatically. So no need to add routes.

Comment: Right you are. You already have this `Route::resource('users', 'UserController');`; which will add the `delete` route. I will update my answer.

Comment: When click button delete, I want the url to here : http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016. How if you don't declared the route as `GET`?

Comment: If I don't declared the route as `GET`, when click button delete, the record was successfully deleted. But, the url to here : http://localhost/mysystem/public/users

Comment: I am not understanding what exactly do you want. But, if you want to redirect to `localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016`, then you have already done that in the `destroy` function o the last line: `return redirect(route('users.index.year', ['year' => $year]));` (I am assuming the route `'users.index.year` is defined).

Comment: If like this : `public function destroy($id)
{
    $year = '2016';
    return redirect(route('users.index.year', ['year' => $year]));
}`. It's success. But if like this : `public function destroy($id, $year)
{
    return redirect(route('users.index.year', ['year' => $year]));
}`. It's failed. you try to update your answer in detail

Comment: I can't update my answer unless I know what you want. Also, you can't pass `$year` to `redirect()` without first defining it. That's why you are getting an error.

Comment: what I want is the data is successfully removed and redirect to the url : localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016. If you do not understand, then I will make a new question, more detailed questions

Comment: I've changed my answer. See if that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or  DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: No need of this, as the OP is using `{!! Form::open ...`

Comment: @Xiaobing Mi, It seems the problem is not there

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not declared in route and may be this is the cause, So change you route:

```
Route::get('users/destroy/{year}', 'UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy.year');
```

to this

```
Route::get('users/destroy/{id}/{year}', 'UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy.year');
```

Hope this solve this cause.

Comment: There is exist error like this : `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:` and the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/destroy/6/2016`. I want the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016`

Comment: Let me know what if you use route without passing year(Consider change for every year place)..? I think it should be work...

Comment: I'm still confused. I just want to be when I click button delete, the row deleted and the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016`. I'm using route to passing year

Comment: @samueltoh May [CRUD Laravel 5 how to link to destroy of Resource Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299202/crud-laravel-5-how-to-link-to-destroy-of-resource-controller) will help to solve this!