# Laravel sending id via route

Tags: laravel, url, url-routing

I have posts, where users able to delete or edit them. And when I redirect them I was sending url with id number, like: `test.dev/delete/15`, where 15 is my id of post which should be deleted. Then I tested sending id in route like `route('delete',['id' => $post->id])`. In the end I realized that both methods include id number in `url`. I mean, for url it shows **url** `test.dev/delete/15` and for **route** it shows `test.dev/delete?id=15`

So I was wondering if we can send id, without showing them in url, I am afraid that **curious** users may try to get use of these flaws

Comment: Try via the request

Comment: send id through hidden input field.

Comment: You will need to check in the controller that the person making the request is allowed to delete the item. If someone tries to delete something that does not belong to them or they dont have the correct permission just return the user somewhere else or back to where they came from

Comment: @Eitan how can I do such request in Blade template, can you give example?

Comment: @Adam, yes exactly I am doing that. So there is no way practical way other than checking it in Back-End?

Comment: Not that I know of, as you will always have to display the id somewhere on the page to send it through either a hidden field or id in the url all of which a user can change.

Comment: @Adam, I see... Yes you are right, thank you All )

Comment: I would make use of laravels route model binding though as if the id of the model is not found ie dosent exist it will just 404 so your only having to check if the user owns or has permission to delete the post that is being passed through you dont have to check is it exists

Comment: Ok ok, I see. Thanks one more time. I have written your answer, and tomorrow I will accept it )

Comment: also consider using DELETE request for deleting items. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299202/crud-laravel-5-how-to-link-to-destroy-of-resource-controller

Comment: @Adam where in the page we always have to display id if passed through hidden input?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal inspect element hidden field values can be changed?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal maybe I could have worded it better, but you get my drift

Comment: @Adam ok. either way it can be modified by user. one idea is to use slug instead of id.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal This is true, as long as each slug is unique

Comment: and still, a slug can be changed...

Comment: @Adam oh. nothing is perfect. still passing id through url is no risk if we check for valid id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will always have to display the **id** somewhere on the page to send it through either a **hidden field** or **id in the url** all of which a user can change. That is why you should check in the **Back-End** if the user has privelege to delete that post or not